# Is it possible to write Android applications in Eclipse environment using of Python?

Tags: android

I want to ask if it is possible to program Android applications in Eclipse environment using Python?

Comment: There is a project called SL4A (Scripting Layer For Android) That allows you to write programs in python that can then be executed on Android. However it offers limited functionality compared to Java. I have no idea if Eclipse supports Python or not. You can read more about the project here: https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a (note that it is not as simple as renaming the file from .java to .py though. That is not going to work at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has bad idea written all over it. Either learn or hire someone to do android code, if you aren't willing to do this, do an html5 responsive app. ( you can also use phone gap if you want the app to be downloadable from the app store, or basically just make a simple app with a webview which points to your responsive site.)